# Add 2 inputs of a form when user press a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In a html form I want to add dynamically two inputs when the user press the `+` button. However it duplicates the submit button and not the 2 inputs. **Is it possible to select the `form-group` that the `+` button belongs?** and duplicate that?

```js
var counter = 1;
$('#form-notifications1')
  .on('click', '.addInput', function() {
    var $template = $('.form-group').slice(-1).clone(true, true).find('input').end()
      .find('.addInput').removeClass('addInput').addClass('removeInput').end()
      .find('[name^="mould-"]').attr('name', 'mould-' + counter).val("").end()
      .find('[name^="email-"]').attr('name', 'email-' + counter).val("").end()
      .find('i').removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus').end();
    $template.insertAfter('.form-group:last');
    $('.form-control:last').focus();
    console.log("+: " + counter);
    counter++;
  })

  // Remove button click handler
  .on('click', '.removeInput', function() {
    var $row = $('.form-group').slice(-1);
    counter--;
    $row.remove();
    console.log("-: " + counter);
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <form id="form-notifications1" method="post " action="# " class="form-horizontal " role="form ">
        <fieldset>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
              <label for="inputName " class="col-xs-2 control-label ">input</label>
              <div class="col-xs-2">
                <select class="js-states form-control " name="mouldId-1">
                  <option></option>
                  <option value="1 ">1</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <label for="inputName" class="col-xs-2 control-label ">Email</label>
              <div class="col-xs-6">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email-1" />
              </div>

              <div class="col-xs-1">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default addInput"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-12 ">
              <button type="submit " class="btn btn-primary ">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*EDIT*

I had a space in `id="form-notifications1 "`that's why it wasn't running... However, it duplicates the button and not the 2 inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following snippet is how you expect it to be, you had a redundant `.slice(-1)` in `var $template = $('.form-group').slice(-1).clone(true, true).find('input').end()` and a lot of not sure for what  ( empty space ) before ending the class.

Also if you want to remove it then you need to fix `var $row = $('.form-group').slice(-1);` into `.slice(-2)`

`.slice(-x)` where `x` is a number is used to select the last `x` element which you're going to select.

Read the following link about [`.slice()`](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) for more info.

```js
var counter = 1;
$('#form-notifications1')
  .on('click', '.addInput', function() {
    var $template = $('.form-group').clone(true, true).find('input').end()
      .find('.addInput').removeClass('addInput').addClass('removeInput').end()
      .find('[name^="mould-"]').attr('name', 'mould-' + counter).val("").end()
      .find('[name^="email-"]').attr('name', 'email-' + counter).val("").end()
      .find('i').removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus').end();
    $template.insertBefore('#mybtn');
    $('.form-control:last').focus();
    console.log("+: " + counter);
    counter++;
  })

  // Remove button click handler
  .on('click', '.removeInput', function() {
    var $row = $('.form-group').slice(-1);
    counter--;
    $row.remove();
    console.log("-: " + counter);
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <form id="form-notifications1" method="post" action="#" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <fieldset>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
              <label for="inputName" class="col-xs-2 control-label">input</label>
              <div class="col-xs-2">
                <select class="js-states form-control" name="mouldId-1">
                  <option></option>
                  <option value="1">1</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <label for="inputName" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Email</label>
              <div class="col-xs-6">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email-1" />
              </div>

              <div class="col-xs-1">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default addInput"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="mybtn" class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <button type="submit " class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of spaces where no spaces belong

old

`<form id="form-notifications1 " method="post " action="# " class="form-horizontal " role="form ">`

new

`<form id="form-notifications1" method="post" action="#" class="form-horizontal" role="form">`